# pyspark: In spite of adding winutils to HADOOP_HOME, getting error: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I set `winutils.exe` path in `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable. I also set other paths such as python,spark,java and all these paths in PATH variable as well for pyspark. When running `pyspark` from command prompt I'm still facing the error :

```
ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.findHadoopBinary(HiveConf.java:2327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:105)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.CurrentThreadClassLoadingStrategy.classForName(CurrentThreadClassLoadingStrategy.java:40)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionUtil.classForName(ReflectionUtil.java:51)
        at py4j.reflection.TypeUtil.forName(TypeUtil.java:243)
        at py4j.commands.ReflectionCommand.getUnknownMember(ReflectionCommand.java:175)
        at py4j.commands.ReflectionCommand.execute(ReflectionCommand.java:87)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `HADOOP_HOME` should not point to `winutils.exe` directly, but to a folder having a  `bin\winutils.exe` in it.

For example

if you have `C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe`, then set `HADOOP_HOME` to `C:\hadoop`